# how to get the date in the format that is displayed in sql table?

Tags: java, oracle, date, date-format

I have an oracle database table with a date column. when I query the table date is displayed in `dd-MMM-yy` format. For example `17-OCT-19` format. But when I query the table from java and print the value I am seeing the date in `yyyy-MM-dd` format. Is there a way where I can fetch the date the same as that is displayed in `dd-MMM-yy` format? I have no idea why the date is getting displayed in a different format in java.

```
DateFormat activityDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date activityDate = activityDateFormat.parse();
activityDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy");
finalActivityDate = activityDateFormat.format(activityDate);
```

I am using the piece of code to convert the date from `yyyy-MM-dd` to `dd-MMM-yy` format. The NLS settings for Date format in the database are `DD-MON-RR`. Is there any reason why I don't get the date the same as `DD-MON-RR`? can someone please help me?

Comment: can you show the code how are you querying it?

Comment: Pass a `LocalDate` object to your query using parameters (`?` placeholders) and `PreparedStatement.setObject()` and don't worry about the format. Formats are for display, not for queries.

Comment: The `DateFormat` and `SimpleDateFormat` classes are notoriously troublesome, `Date` poorly designed too and all long outdated. Use the `LocalDate` class I mentioned, it's from java.time, the modern Java date and time API.

Comment: Formatting is up to the client application and desktop format/territory settings. The internal `date` value as stored in the database is binary data.

Answer (score 0):

Select the date column as string and format it dd-mmm-yy from the SQL query.

The client you are using to query Oracle, SQL Developer is often used, is the one formatting the date.
Java gets the date as a date data type and will use whatever is the default format when converting it to a string